# Flip Flop Switch for a Rocket

Tags: arduino, mosfet, cmos

I am looking for the best (closest) way to create a solid state version of a dual coil latching relay. Essentially, a circuit that has two inputs (on & off) that when pulsed will flip flop the state of a FET from on to off, but when the inputs hard disconnect the state remains in either on or off (power to the circuit remains).

The background is an experimental university rocket that has an electronics package. While it is on the pad, you want the electronics package off for safety and then you want to turn it on remotely (through a gpio pin output from a ground tether). If the launch is scrubbed you need to turn it off remotely. In many ways, a dual coil latching relay would be perfect (no "power on" the rocket required), but the magnetic latching would not reliably hold up to the G forces and physical stresses of launch/landing. The two inputs are only connected, while it is on the pad. Once the vehicle launches they become physically disconnected, so the circuit cannot be dependent on their state.

So, I am considering some type of flip flop circuit that switches a FET. The circuit would need to be powered up separately, but would have little drain and would present little risk to the fueling operating.

Any creative ideas on how to simplify this? I am more software than I am hardware and my EE skills are a bit rusty, but this should be a pretty simple circuit.  Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MOSFET switch with two on/off momentary buttons -- asking for critique](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43216/mosfet-switch-with-two-on-off-momentary-buttons-asking-for-critique)

Comment: Two Schmitt inverters in series  with a resistor from input to output acts as a latch - drive with more current than resistor can source and it follows Vin. Remove Vin and it self latches. Drive FET with that. Whoops - I now see that that's about what Tony shows but he's used non-Schmitt and an added cap.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this.  It's not much current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNvG28.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>